# Crud operation in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an assignment in ASP.NET MVC and I try to write a crud operation without Entity Framework, but the code is not working correctly.

This is my code:

```
List<bookModel> books = new List<bookModel>();

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-VKO8311;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True");

string query = "SELECT * FROM books";

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

try
{
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        books.Add(new bookModel
                      {
                          Title  = reader["Title of book"].ToString(),
                          Author = reader["Author"].ToString(),
                          Price  = reader["Price"].ToString()
                      });
        con.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    con.Close();
}

return View(books);

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult NewBook()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add New Book";
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewBook(bookModel model)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-VKO8311;Initial Catalog=BookStore;Integrated Security=True");

    string query = "insert into books values(@Ti, @au, @pr)";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con);

    command.Parameters.Add("@Ti", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@Ti"].Value = model.Title;
    command.Parameters.Add("@au", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@au"].Value = model.author;
    command.Parameters.Add("@pr", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters["@pr"].Value = model.Price; 

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("insert was successful");
        return RedirectToAction("books");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        con.Close();
    }

    return View();
}
```

The `books.cshtml` does not show the result from the database and also the `newbook.cshtml` does not redirect the create result in the database also.

Any help please?

Comment: should post all books controller and cshtml file to question

Comment: this is also i have only one controller that i use in the project so is no problem do this do uploed the cshtml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needs refactoring, but the biggest issue is where you are closing your connection.  You don't do it while you're iterating the data reader.  Also, take the connection close out of your exception handler.  You're better off enclosing it in a using block.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    books.Add(new bookModel
    {
        Title  = reader["Title of book"].ToString(),
        Author = reader["Author"].ToString(),
        Price  = reader["Price"].ToString()
    });

}
```